# Create lag / lead time series with by groups in Julia?

Tags: group-by, time-series, julia, lag

I am wondering if there is an easy way to create a lag (or lead) of a time series variable in Julia according to a by group or condition? For example: I have a dataset of the following form

```
julia> df1 = DataFrame(var1=["a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b"],
                             var2=[0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3])
8×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ var1   │ var2  │
│     │ String │ Int64 │
├─────┼────────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ a      │ 0     │
│ 2   │ a      │ 1     │
│ 3   │ a      │ 2     │
│ 4   │ a      │ 3     │
│ 5   │ b      │ 0     │
│ 6   │ b      │ 1     │
│ 7   │ b      │ 2     │
│ 8   │ b      │ 3     │
```

And I want to create a variable `lag2` that contains the values in `var2` lagged by 2. However, this should be done grouped by var1 so that the first two observations in the 'b' group do not get the last two values of the 'a' group. Rather they should be set to missing or zero or some default value.

I have tried the following code which produces the following error.

```
julia> df2 = df1 |> @groupby(_.var1) |> @mutate(lag2 = lag(_.var2,2)) |> DataFrame

ERROR: MethodError: no method matching merge(::Grouping{String,NamedTuple{(:var1, :var2),Tuple{String,Int64}}}, ::NamedTuple{(:lag2,),Tuple{ShiftedArray{Int64,Missing,1,QueryOperators.GroupColumnArrayView{Int64,Grouping{String,NamedTuple{(:var1, :var2),Tuple{String,Int64}}},:var2}}}})
Closest candidates are:
  merge(::NamedTuple{,T} where T<:Tuple, ::NamedTuple) at namedtuple.jl:245
  merge(::NamedTuple{an,T} where T<:Tuple, ::NamedTuple{bn,T} where T<:Tuple) where {an, bn} at namedtuple.jl:233
  merge(::NamedTuple, ::NamedTuple, ::NamedTuple...) at namedtuple.jl:249
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] (::var"#437#442")(::Grouping{String,NamedTuple{(:var1, :var2),Tuple{String,Int64}}}) at /Users/kayvon/.julia/packages/Query/AwBtd/src/query_translation.jl:58
 [2] iterate at /Users/kayvon/.julia/packages/QueryOperators/g4G21/src/enumerable/enumerable_map.jl:25 [inlined]
 [3] iterate at /Users/kayvon/.julia/packages/Tables/TjjiP/src/tofromdatavalues.jl:45 [inlined]
 [4] buildcolumns at /Users/kayvon/.julia/packages/Tables/TjjiP/src/fallbacks.jl:185 [inlined]
 [5] columns at /Users/kayvon/.julia/packages/Tables/TjjiP/src/fallbacks.jl:237 [inlined]
 [6] #DataFrame#453(::Bool, ::Type{DataFrame}, ::QueryOperators.EnumerableMap{Union{},QueryOperators.EnumerableIterable{Grouping{String,NamedTuple{(:var1, :var2),Tuple{String,Int64}}},QueryOperators.EnumerableGroupBy{Grouping{String,NamedTuple{(:var1, :var2),Tuple{String,Int64}}},String,NamedTuple{(:var1, :var2),Tuple{String,Int64}},QueryOperators.EnumerableIterable{NamedTuple{(:var1, :var2),Tuple{String,Int64}},Tables.DataValueRowIterator{NamedTuple{(:var1, :var2),Tuple{String,Int64}},Tables.Schema{(:var1, :var2),Tuple{String,Int64}},Tables.RowIterator{NamedTuple{(:var1, :var2),Tuple{Array{String,1},Array{Int64,1}}}}}},var"#434#439",var"#435#440"}},var"#437#442"}) at /Users/kayvon/.julia/packages/DataFrames/S3ZFo/src/other/tables.jl:40
 [7] DataFrame(::QueryOperators.EnumerableMap{Union{},QueryOperators.EnumerableIterable{Grouping{String,NamedTuple{(:var1, :var2),Tuple{String,Int64}}},QueryOperators.EnumerableGroupBy{Grouping{String,NamedTuple{(:var1, :var2),Tuple{String,Int64}}},String,NamedTuple{(:var1, :var2),Tuple{String,Int64}},QueryOperators.EnumerableIterable{NamedTuple{(:var1, :var2),Tuple{String,Int64}},Tables.DataValueRowIterator{NamedTuple{(:var1, :var2),Tuple{String,Int64}},Tables.Schema{(:var1, :var2),Tuple{String,Int64}},Tables.RowIterator{NamedTuple{(:var1, :var2),Tuple{Array{String,1},Array{Int64,1}}}}}},var"#434#439",var"#435#440"}},var"#437#442"}) at /Users/kayvon/.julia/packages/DataFrames/S3ZFo/src/other/tables.jl:31
 [8] |>(::QueryOperators.EnumerableMap{Union{},QueryOperators.EnumerableIterable{Grouping{String,NamedTuple{(:var1, :var2),Tuple{String,Int64}}},QueryOperators.EnumerableGroupBy{Grouping{String,NamedTuple{(:var1, :var2),Tuple{String,Int64}}},String,NamedTuple{(:var1, :var2),Tuple{String,Int64}},QueryOperators.EnumerableIterable{NamedTuple{(:var1, :var2),Tuple{String,Int64}},Tables.DataValueRowIterator{NamedTuple{(:var1, :var2),Tuple{String,Int64}},Tables.Schema{(:var1, :var2),Tuple{String,Int64}},Tables.RowIterator{NamedTuple{(:var1, :var2),Tuple{Array{String,1},Array{Int64,1}}}}}},var"#434#439",var"#435#440"}},var"#437#442"}, ::Type) at ./operators.jl:854
 [9] top-level scope at none:0
```

Appreciate any help with this approach or alternate approaches. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### EDIT

Putting this edit to the top as it works in DataFrames 1.0 so reflects the stable API:

Under DataFrames.jl 0.22.2 the correct syntax is:

```
julia> combine(groupby(df1, :var1), :var2 => Base.Fix2(lag, 2) => :var2_l2)
8×2 DataFrame
 Row │ var1    var2_l2 
     │ String  Int64?  
─────┼─────────────────
   1 │ a       missing 
   2 │ a       missing 
   3 │ a             0
   4 │ a             1
   5 │ b       missing 
   6 │ b       missing 
   7 │ b             0
   8 │ b             1
```

Another alternative to the maybe slightly arcane `Base.Fix2` syntax you could use an anonymous function `(x -> lag(x, 2))` (note the enclosing parens are required due to operator precedence).

---

Original answer:

You definitely had the right idea - I don't work with Query.jl but this can easily be done with basic DataFrames syntax:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> import ShiftedArrays: lag

julia> df1 = DataFrame(var1=["a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b"],
                                    var2=[0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3]);

julia> by(df1, :var1, var2_l2 = :var2 => Base.Fix2(lag, 2)))
8×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ var1   │ var2_l2 │
│     │ String │ Int64⍰  │
├─────┼────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ a      │ missing │
│ 2   │ a      │ missing │
│ 3   │ a      │ 0       │
│ 4   │ a      │ 1       │
│ 5   │ b      │ missing │
│ 6   │ b      │ missing │
│ 7   │ b      │ 0       │
│ 8   │ b      │ 1       │
```

Note that I used `Base.Fix2` here to get a single argument version of `lag`. This is essentially the same as defining your own `l2(x) = lag(x, 2)` and then using `l2` in the `by` call. If you do define your own `l2` function you can also set the default value like `l2(x) = lag(x, 2, default = -1000)` if you want to avoid missing values:

```
julia> l2(x) = lag(x, 2, default = -1000)
l2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> by(df1, :var1, var2_l2 = :var2 => l2)
8×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ var1   │ var2_l2 │
│     │ String │ Int64   │
├─────┼────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ a      │ -1000   │
│ 2   │ a      │ -1000   │
│ 3   │ a      │ 0       │
│ 4   │ a      │ 1       │
│ 5   │ b      │ -1000   │
│ 6   │ b      │ -1000   │
│ 7   │ b      │ 0       │
│ 8   │ b      │ 1       │
```

Comment: That worked great, thank you! As a follow up question, is there a way to do this without dropping any variables that are not part of the grouping? For example, if there were a date variable with values (1/1/20,1/2/20,1/3/20,1/4/20) for each group in var1. I would not want to group by these but I would like them in the DataFrame that is output.

Comment: Two ways of doing this - either use groupby instead of by, or just join the result of my answer above back onto your original DataFrame. The next version of DataFrames.jl will also have a mutate function that can do what you're looking for.

Comment: how does do this now that `by` is deprecated?

Comment: I have edited the answer. Currently we have stabilized the API of DataFrames.jl so you should expect that what works under 0.22 release will work in the long term. We are now only adding new functionalities without breaking old one (unless it is a bug).